# avqueueplayer play in background mode issue

Tags: ios, background-process, avqueueplayer

I use avqueueplayer to play some very short audios. Once an item is completed, it shall pause for 2 second and then play the next item.

The problem is if the player is paused and at the same time, I press home button, it will not play the next item unless I re-enter the app.

The background play works fine if I press home button, and the player is not in paused status. How Should I sovle this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio will not be interrupted if it is continuous. But you need to declare your app's `RemoteControlEvents` for audio to be played in the background if it is, as you explained, paused or stopped.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Comment: I did this.What I mean is once an item is comleted，I invoke [Player pause] to give a delay, and the perform selector [player play] delayed for 2 second, So if [Player pause] is called, and at the same time I enter background mode, the play will not continue playing.

Comment: In that case you should add secondary callback for starting to play music if the app enters background. `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];` 
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];`

Comment: Yes, I call player play when app will resign active and it works. Thank you. How brilliant you are.